# How to move each value in a row one position by a position in the array?

Tags: python, numpy

How to move the values in the field by scrolling by one position a position in sequence? Then replace unnecessary values with the number zero?

Example:
My array

```
np.array([[51 52 53 54 55 56 57]
 [41 42 43 44 45 46 47]
 [31 32 33 34 35 36 37]
 [21 22 23 24 25 26 27]
 [11 12 13 14 15 16 17]])
```

I need:

```
[[0 0 0 0 51 52 53]
 [0 0 0 41 42 43 0]
 [0 0 31 32 33 0 0]
 [0 21 22 23 0 0 0]
 [11 12 13 0 0 0 0]]
```

Here we see that the last line does not shift and unnecessary values are zero. In the next line, the first three numbers are shifted to the right and the others are reset. I would need such a sequence. It is possible?

array's shape is not fixed

Comment: Is the array's shape fixed?

Comment: I don't quite see how unnecessary values are defined and when to shift the values.

Comment: it can be said that we set the first three in each line as fundamental values, the others are unnecessary

Comment: No the shape of array's is not fixed

Comment: is this a numpy array or a regular list of list?

Comment: This is a numpy

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the number of elements shifted to the right is also arbitrary (`elements_shifted > 0`). Here is my first attempt:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57],
             [41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47],
             [31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37],
             [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27],
             [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]])

elements_shifted = 3 # You can change this number to another desired one > 0

b = [row[:elements_shifted] for row in a]
a_shifted = np.zeros(a.shape)

start_idx = -elements_shifted

a_shifted[0][start_idx:] = b[0]
for i in range(1, len(a)):
    start_idx -= 1
    if -start_idx > a.shape[1]:
        a_shifted[i][:elements_shifted] = b[i]
    else:
        a_shifted[i][start_idx:start_idx + elements_shifted] = b[i]

print(a_shifted)
```

Output:

```
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0. 51. 52. 53.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. 41. 42. 43.  0.]
 [ 0.  0. 31. 32. 33.  0.  0.]
 [ 0. 21. 22. 23.  0.  0.  0.]
 [11. 12. 13.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is to create a row by concatenating left side, array row item,  and right side.

This will take the number of rows and columns in the array and set zeros to all values based on the number of rows in the array.

```
import numpy as np
my_array = np.array([[51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57],
 [41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47],
 [31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37],
 [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27],
 [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]])

my_new_array = np.zeros(my_array.shape)
x = np.shape(my_array)[1]
y = np.shape(my_array)[0]-1
for i,item in enumerate(my_array):
    left_side = [0] * (y-i)
    right_side = [0] * i
    row_item = np.concatenate((left_side,item[:(x-y)],right_side),axis = 0)
    my_new_array[i] = row_item
print (my_new_array)
```

The output of this will be:

```
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0. 51. 52. 53.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. 41. 42. 43.  0.]
 [ 0.  0. 31. 32. 33.  0.  0.]
 [ 0. 21. 22. 23.  0.  0.  0.]
 [11. 12. 13.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
```